# Does wordpress offer the ability to edit theme structure via the online editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to do something that is not offered in the basic theme options and would like to edit some backend code. Can someone tell me if this is possible to do via the online editor or if I need to create a local environment?

Here is the current menu showing articles on the site:

[Current Dropdown Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om32j.png)

**What I am trying to do**:

As you can see right now the menu is only displaying the title of the article. My goal is to display in excerpt from the article. This function is available for blog post on other parts of the site and I would like to make it available in the menu location.

Here is a list of the files I am able to edit online via Wordpress:

[Available Wordpress Files Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq9e5.png)

Is what I need to edit on this list?  I know once I find where I need to be working I can figure this out. Since I am totally clueless about wordpress I don't know where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you need to edit?  The layout of the posts? How many appear?  Please provide more information with what you need to modify.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Doing that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the backend files. Here is an overview of what the different files are responsible for: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#the-template-hierarchy-in-detail

Here is a dedicate article for excerpts:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt

Comment: Thank you for the resources. Will review them now and try to work through it.

Comment: I searched and was unable to find what I was looking for within my wordpress files. Can you view my files list and give me some input?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When linking to external resources, please quote the relevant details. Here's the guide on [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Hey so it is actually very easy to edit the theme files and view them through a plugin called [Wp-Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/).

Just install it, activate it and go to Appearance > Theme Editor and then you will see your existing files in your theme.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find that. The only problem is I dont know which file contains the structure of the main menu.

Comment: Great, most likely you will find that under header.php